# :confirm! ignored in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html, oop

I am running a Rails application and it is running well except for a small part of the code.
I need the browser to ask for approval when I click 'Destroy' but it doesnt.
This ia a part of my view in `index.html.erb`

```
<td><%= button_to 'Destroy', {:action => 'destroy', :id => publisher},
{:method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure?'} %></td>
```

I cant find anything wrong with the syntax and cant find anything to suggest why this isnt working
Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below syntax instead.

```
<%= button_to "Destroy", { :action => "delete", :id => publisher }, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete %>
```

Make sure you include the Javascript libraries inside of your layout file:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

If neither of these work please post full view and explain how you define your routes please.

thanks

Comment: feel really stupid...the mistake was that I forgot `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>` in layout...thanks :(

Answer (score 1):

Do note, that the [confirm option is officially deprecated and will be removed in rails 4.0](http://www.edgerails.info/2012/7/23/whats-new-30/) and that you should use

```
<%= button_to 'Destroy', {:action => 'destroy', :id => publisher},
{:method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?'}} %>
```

Comment: thats very useful to know, thanks alot will try and look to replacing it in the future.

Comment: Given that it didn't solve your problem, I don't feel the answer should be upvoted, Amy.

Comment: It does help in knowing what's coming up next; so worth upvoting in my view ;-)

Comment: Looks like there's a typo.  Shouldn't :data be data: per http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html?

Comment: Seems there is a typo, but it's not the one you pointed out, @JohnCreamer, I've fixed it

Comment: @JohnCramer: data: .. is the "new", Ruby 1.9-ish syntax for hashes, :data => ... is the old one. There is no difference otherwise.